# PDF not opening correctly on web browser for files on remote folder

Tags: apache, pdf, remote-access

I'm using a Debian EC2 instance running a Apache2 server (from the open semantic search package).

When I try to open a pdf file in the web browser (inline?), it opens a modified version of it when the file is located on a remote folder but not when the file is located locally.

I saw recommendation (http://www.devside.net/wamp-server/forcing-a-pdf-or-doc-to-open-in-browser-rather-than-downloading) to modify the Apache configuration file to include:

```
<LocationMatch "\.(?i:pdf)$">
    ForceType application/pdf
    Header set Content-Disposition inline
</LocationMatch>
```

I tried adding it to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

But when I restart the apache server, I get the following error message:

apachectl[16425]: AH00526: Syntax error on line 207 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf:
apachectl[16425]: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

My questions are:

1. Which Apache configuration file should I modify?
2. Is this modification going to open the pdf file in the web browser inline without downloading / modifying the pdf file when coming from a remote folder?

Thanks!
Yoann

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that it isn't the PDF that is getting corrupted, but the images inside of it.

Some time ago, some server admins were having problems with images getting corrupted by apache2. See for example [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/96460/apache-returns-truncated-image) and [drupalQuestion](https://www.drupal.org/node/57081).

The proposed solution is to change a couple of settings in the apache2 config file. I suspect memory mapping is the issue, which can be turned off by adding the following command to apache2.conf:

```
EnableMMAP Off
```

I hope this helps!